# Angular 10: undefined error despite if (... != null)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a var product which I load from the backend. If there are images to that product, I want to load them as well. This already works, but only when the product has images.
If the product has no images I want to skip that product, so I use this:

```
if (product.images[0] != null) {
         //do something with product.images[0]
}
```

Inside the if is the only place in my code where I use product.images[0], but I still get this Error:

[image: error message]

Comment: If `product.images` is `undefined`, then attempting to access element 0 (`[0]`) will fail. The proper thing to do is check `product.images` *first* and then check its length or `[0]`.

Comment: To be clear.. null is not the same as undefined..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check:

```
if (product && product.images && product.images.length > 0) {
  // do something with product.images[0]
}
```